# How do I fix my bot not finding a keyword in an embedded message? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that searches embedded messages for keywords. I've got the code below:

```
botprefix = '!'
client = discord.Client(command_prefix=botprefix)
reurl = 'https://www.example.com'
@client.event
async def check_all_message(reurl, message):
    for e in message.embeds:
        if any(item and reurl in item for item in (e.title, e.footer, e.description)):
            return True
        if e.fields:
            for field in e.fields:
                if reurl in field.name or reurl in field.value:
                    return True
    return False

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!embed'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title='https://www.example.com',url = 'https://www.example.com')
        await client.send_message(message.channel,embed = embed)
    if check_all_message == True:
        driver.refresh()
```

I've got an example embedded message set up with the !embed command and the bot is then supposed to search the embedded message, set the check_all_message value to False if the keyword is not found and to True when it is found. Then it is supposed to refresh a webdriver that was defined in a different function globally. However even when the url in the embedded message is exactly the same as the one I'm looking for, it doesn't refresh the driver. Where am I making a mistake? I appreciate any help as a newbie :)

Comment: `if check_all_message == True` that conditional doesn't call your function but instead, will compare the function with a boolean (which will always evaluate to false). You'll need to call the function with brackets and pass in some arguments. `check_all_message(some_url, some_message)`.

Comment: Show your research please. Have you tried debugging any of this? Have you proven that the expected event is being raised?

Comment: @jdv like I said, I'm very much a newbie so no, I haven't tried nor proven any of those things.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Newbies have to start somewhere! See [ask]. You are expected to show your research and give debugging a try. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @jdv thanks, will do next time :)